Matlab Induction Motor Torque Characteristics
I'm having trouble with getting the correct plot from a coupled induction motor/DC generator system for an electric drives class. How it is supposed to work is the DC generator serves to simulate a mechanical load which can be altered with the armature winding resistor. The torque curve of the induction motor will then be altered because the power factor will be increased by an increasingly resistive load. However, with the configuration I have currently, the torque curve remains unchanged for any value of armature resistance. The torque curve is correct from what I can tell but adding the resistance isn't properly realized by the circuit. My guess is the coupling isn't correct but I'm not sure. 
I believe I need to ramp the induction machine to simulate a range of speeds to plot the torque over, and I know the two machines have to be "mechanically" coupled and I think I'm on the right track but changing the highlighted resistance doesn't change the torque curve at all. All I can get is the following torque curve, which I assume is at nearly no load and the changing load resistance is just not seen by the system because of a coupling issue. Any help is appreciated, God bless.
